# detect browser size and apply css for every resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this function that I use to apply some css to a menu when browser is resized or when the menu is rendering on different resolutions. 
My problem is this, why the browser is not interpreting correctly my function? because when I resize my browser in full mode from half mode the browser interprets only `'800-1024'` resolution but if I do `ctrl+f5` in browser (clear all) interprets correctly my resolution so what is wrong in my function?

```
function renderMenuCorection(){
                if ($('#containerHeader').exists()) {
                    var resizeObject = {

                        '0-640': '9px,2px,-3px,12px',
                        '640-800': '10px,2px,-5px,12px',
                        '800-1024': '10px,8px,-8px,15px',
                        '1024-1300': '12px,12px,-13px,11px',
                        '1300-2000': ',20px,-21px'
                    }

                    var win = $(window);
                    var win_width = win.width();

                    if (win_width > 0 && win_width <= 640) {
                        var value = getValueByKey(resizeObject, '0-640');
                        modifayMenu(value);
                    }
                    else 
                        if (win_width > 640 && win_width <= 800) {
                            var value = getValueByKey(resizeObject, '640-800');
                            modifayMenu(value);
                        }
                        else 
                            if (win_width > 800 && win_width <= 1024) {
                                var value = getValueByKey(resizeObject, '800-1024');
                                modifayMenu(value);
                                alert("I'm on: 800-1024 ," + win_width);
                            }
                            else 
                                if (win_width > 1024 && win_width <= 1300) {
                                    var value = getValueByKey(resizeObject, '1024-1300');
                                    modifayMenu(value);
                                    alert("I'm on: 1024-1300 ," + win_width);
                                }

                                else 
                                    if (win_width > 1300 ) {
                                       var value = getValueByKey(resizeObject, '1300-2000');
                                        modifayMenu(value);
                                    }
                }
            }
          function modifayMenu(value){
            var vals = value.split(',')
                $('#containerHeader').find('.roundMenuLi').each(function(index, item){
                    $(item).find('a').css('font-size', vals[0]);
                    $(item).css('padding-right', vals[1]);
                    $(item).css('padding-left', vals[1]);
                    $(item).find('#secondUl').css('margin-left', vals[2]);
                    $(item).css('padding-bottom', vals[3]);
              });

            }
          function getValueByKey(obj, myKey){

                $.each(obj, function(key, value){

                    if (key == myKey) {
                        returnValue = value;
                    }
                });
                return returnValue;
            }
```

Thank you !

Comment: Read up on Reactive Web Design or the older Elastic Web Design techniques. You shouldn't be doing this. Also look at CSS media queries.

Comment: @Dai and how this will help me now ?

Comment: Have look at [mediaqueri.es](http://mediaqueri.es) or google for responsive web design.

Comment: Better use Responsive Web Design techniques.

Comment: Because we want to make you a better web developer :) Client scripts should not be concerned with how a page looks, but how it behaves. What you're wanting to do is achievable with CSS media queries without using any scripts, so it will be faster too, and work on browsers that have scripting disabled.

Comment: @Dai Thank you, I know what media queries is but tell that to IE8 :(

Comment: What does IE8 have to do with it? If you're battling an IE8 bug then look at conditional comments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use CSS3 and its media queries. Example:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    /* some CSS for small resolution */
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    /* some CSS for large resolution */
}
```

Comment: @burebistaruler there shims for adding media queries support in IE https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Answer (score 2):

you main you want to create a responsive design this [link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design) can help you.

building responsive design you must consider

- Flexible Grid
- Flexible Images
- Media Quires

/* below code play important part of your responsive design without that you cannot achieve what you want */

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` /* put this before the end tag of head */

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {

}

@media (min-width: 720px) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your code, but most likely you are only calling the function once on pageload. In order to make this do what you want, you will have to attach an event listener and call the code each time the window is resized.

As commented above, consider researching Responsive Web Design to utilize native browser functionality so you don't have to roll your own script to do this. A good place to start is an A List Apart article under the same name.

Comment: the function is called every time when browser is resized :         <body onresize="renderMenuCorection();" onload="renderMenuCorection();">

Answer (score 1):

Media-queries are the best solution as Pavel remarks, besides they're much faster than all the access to the DOM you're making using your code. 
The compatibility problem with IE8 can be solved using a JavaScript pluging called [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond%29). Haven't tried it but it seems a good solution to your problem.